# How to release a hydraulic brake (tightened with wheel off)

Tags: wheels, hydraulic-disc-brake

On my fairly new bike, I had to remove the front wheel on storage. I must have accidentally pressed the brake lever or so, because now the brakes are tight so that the disc won't fit in the brake (see the picture below). Is there any easy way how to release the brakes now? It should be **Shimano BR-M396 180 160 mm** if the catalog is correct.

[image]

Comment: The standard best practice for disks is NEVER close them without the rotor in place.  Next time you take the wheel out, slip something thin between them as a preventer.  You can use a plastic tyre lever to try and separate the pads.

Comment: @Criggie Yeah, I know. I was considering storing the bike with front wheel off (to save space), but I'll probably abandon the idea (for multiple reasons, the brakes being one of them). Still, thanks!